# Bulk Insert Fails at First Float

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

Trying to do bulk insert in SQL 2014 Express but receiving an error. Seems like the process fails on the first float value of the table it is uploading to.

I am using excel office 2013 and save as CSV with "," delimitor. 
Have already removed any commas with "_" before processing
Change my file extension to a txt before processing

Error:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 7 (NEW_PARTS_TERM).
```

Sample Import File is:

```
ID,DEALER_NUM,DEALER_NAME,NEW_WARRANTY_SKU_NUM,NEW_WARRANTY_SKU_NAME,NEW_PARTS_TERM,EARNING_TYPE,PROGRAM_TYPE,PURCHDT,FAILDT,CLAIMCNT,TOTAL_LOSSES
1,1060,Officemax,189400,OM 2YR ADH PREM SVC $450-$549.99 P,24.00,U,SERVICE,4/1/2015,8/1/2015,1.00,341.16
2,1060,Officemax,189400,OM 2YR ADH PREM SVC $450-$549.99 P,24.00,U,SERVICE,4/1/2015,9/1/2015,1.00,181.16
```

*** Executing Stored Procedure ***

```
Exec [dbo].[BulkInsertFiles] 'Losses', 'C:\Users\hb\Desktop\FileUpload\', 'AllCNA_LossesDataThru_Aug-2016_Purch.txt'
```

*** Stored Procedure Code ***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsertFiles]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @INDEX nvarchar(20),
        @PATH nvarchar(100),
        @FILENAME nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Varaibles
    DECLARE @FULLPath nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(MAX)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @FULLPATH = '''' + @Path + @FILENAME +''''

    SET @QUERY = 'BULK INSERT ' + @Index +
    ' FROM' + @FULLPATH + ' WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  
        ROWTERMINATOR = '''',
        TABLOCK
    )';
    --Print @query;
    EXEC(@query);

END
```

*** Table Schema ***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Losses](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DEALER_NUM] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [DEALER_NAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [UNDERWRITER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NEW_WARRANTY_SKU_NUM] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [NEW_WARRANTY_SKU_NAME] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [NEW_PARTS_TERM] [float] NULL,
    [EARNING_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PROGRAM_TYPE] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [PURCHDT] [date] NULL,
    [FAILDT] [date] NULL,
    [CLAIMCNT] [float] NULL,
    [TOTAL_LOSSES] [float] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: does your file have headers? it could be that its trying to read the header and insert it into the float column.

Comment: according to Microsoft The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers. Skipping headers is not supported by the BULK INSERT statement. When skipping rows, the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the field terminators, and does not validate the data in the fields of skipped rows.

Comment: I switched everything in the table to a varchar and that solved the float issue, but now it is complaining about the last column Total_Losses

Comment: how about changing ROWTERMINATOR = '''' to ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'

Comment: Kamran: Yes, I already had in my script, not sure why it did not show up when I pasted in Stack

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the number of fields in the table and data, I matched them and fixed my data.

Did not need to remove the header.